# How do i find the largest value of an item in a nested dict in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following dict with a nested dict "Emotions":

I am trying to find an easy way to return the top 2 Emotion "Type" with largest 2 "Confidence" values ( in the case of this dict, it's "CONFUSED" & "ANGRY"

```
[
    {
        "AgeRange": {
            "High": 52,
            "Low": 36
        },
        "Emotions": [
            {
                "Confidence": 22.537073135375977,
                "Type": "ANGRY"
            },
            {
                "Confidence": 1.3983955383300781,
                "Type": "SAD"
            },
            {
                "Confidence": 1.2260702848434448,
                "Type": "DISGUSTED"
            },
            {
                "Confidence": 2.291703939437866,
                "Type": "FEAR"
            },
            {
                "Confidence": 8.114240646362305,
                "Type": "HAPPY"
            },
            {
                "Confidence": 10.546235084533691,
                "Type": "SURPRISED"
            },
            {
                "Confidence": 18.409439086914062,
                "Type": "CALM"
            },
            {
                "Confidence": 35.47684097290039,
                "Type": "CONFUSED"
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

i have tried things like `dictmax = max(dict[Emotions][Confidence] key=dict.get)` but that doesnt seem to work, and i am at a loss. I feel like there should be an easy way to retrieve just the Type, based upon the value of Confidence.

Comment: if `t` is your thing above: `print(sorted(t[0]["Emotions"], key = lambda x: -x["Confidence"])[:2])`

Comment: i also think the issue complicating the matter is that its not a clean mapping like CONFUSED: 35.47684097290039, but has its key stored in Type. I really hope someone knows of a simple way to pull this info.

Comment: Is 'AgeRange' relevant to this question? If not, can you edit it out, to keep the example minimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```py
for d in my_list:
    out=sorted(d['Emotions'],key=lambda x:x['Confidence'],reverse=True)[:2]
```

---

```
[{'Confidence': 35.47684097290039, 'Type': 'CONFUSED'},
 {'Confidence': 22.537073135375977, 'Type': 'ANGRY'}]
```

---

You can use [`nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) also.

```
from heapq import nlargest
for d in a:
    out=nlargest(2,d['Emotions'],key=lambda x:x['Confidence'])
```

Comment: the "for d in my_list:
    out=sorted(d['Emotions'],key=lambda x:x['Confidence'],reverse=True)[:2]" line worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help. If it worked accept this as answer and upvote. @killyb

Comment: what does the "x:x" part of the code doing here? i get everything else @Ch3steR

Comment: Those are lambda functions @killyb. `lambda x: some operation` what this does is it passes `x` to `some operation` and returns the resultant value.

Comment: @killyb Take a look at [lambda functions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and [here too](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/)

Answer (score 1):

Ch3steR's answer works, but I'd like to propose a solution with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a library for dealing with data analysis (using DataFrame objects, which allow for easy data manipulation).

In your example, let's just take the relevant part of the example:

```
emotions = [{'Confidence': 22.537073135375977, 'Type': 'ANGRY'},
 {'Confidence': 1.3983955383300781, 'Type': 'SAD'},
 {'Confidence': 1.2260702848434448, 'Type': 'DISGUSTED'},
 {'Confidence': 2.291703939437866, 'Type': 'FEAR'},
 {'Confidence': 8.114240646362305, 'Type': 'HAPPY'},
 {'Confidence': 10.546235084533691, 'Type': 'SURPRISED'},
 {'Confidence': 18.409439086914062, 'Type': 'CALM'},
 {'Confidence': 35.47684097290039, 'Type': 'CONFUSED'}]
```

This can be cast into a pandas DataFrame object:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(emotions)
```

yields

```
    Confidence  Type
0   22.537073   ANGRY
1   1.398396    SAD
2   1.226070    DISGUSTED
3   2.291704    FEAR
4   8.114241    HAPPY
5   10.546235   SURPRISED
6   18.409439   CALM
7   35.476841   CONFUSED
```

This object can be sorted by any column (e.g. Confidence), with the `.sort_values` method, the last two (or any other number) of rows can be selected with the `.tail(2)` method, and finally, the 'Type' column can be selected. To sup it up:

```
pd.DataFrame(emotions).sort_values('Confidence').tail(2)['Type'].values
```

yields

```
array(['ANGRY', 'CONFUSED'], dtype=object)
```

If you want the top 1, and not top n (for n>1), it's faster and simpler to search for the maximum instead of sorting:

```
emotions.loc[emotions['Confidence'].idxmax(),'Type']
```

yields

```
'CONFUSED'
```

This is not faster than Ch3steR's answer, but the code is more straight-forward (once you know the pandas library), and easy to "scale up" to more complex data analysis which you might need later on.

Comment: using Pandas, how would i map a new variable to the emotion type with the highest confidence? @itamar-mushkin

Comment: would it be var = pd.DataFrame(emotions).sort_values('Confidence').tail(1)['Type'].values

Comment: Almost. `.tail` produces an array (even if it is with size 1), so you need `var = pd.DataFrame(emotions).sort_values('Confidence').tail(1)['Type'].values[0]`. But you don't want to sort them all to find the maximum, it's easier to just get the maximum. I'll edit.